# Two matrices have the same eigenvalue ...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is an testexam question and that requires true or false and some explanataion.

2 (n x n) matrices have the same eigenvalue Pi, does A - B have eigenvalue 0?

Comment: No. In fact, the sum of two singular matrices may not be singular.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Can you elaborate on that please? It was an exam question and didn't really understand how to prove it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\pi &0 \\
0 &0
\end{pmatrix},
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0\\
0 &\pi
\end{pmatrix}.$$